# How to get 'enter' button keypress event listener?

Tags: jquery, html

this is my following code:

```
<div class="search_box">
<input type="text" class="search_text" placeholder="search">
</div>
```

what i want is, how to get `'enter'` button event listener and then get the value of the textbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Jquery:

```
$('.search_text').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
       // do something here 
    }
});
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("id_of_textbox")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76qabk1a/17/)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be with the [keydown](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) Event.

```js
$(document).on('keydown', '.search_text', function (e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if(keyCode === 13) {
    // prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // get input value
    console.log($(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
Type something and press enter<br>
<input type="text" class="search_text">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```